# Jtable Row Span and Column Span

Tags: swing, jtable, desktop-application, java

Is there any way to implement row span and colspan in JTable like html table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a really old example. I don't know if it still works:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/MultiSpanCellTableExample.htm

Comment: Is there any easy way to do this ? i really cant understand the code

Comment: No, there is no easy way to do this. You are basically creating a new TableUI to do this.