# creation of jtable of this format in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want create a jtable of this format is it possible?

```
---------------------------------------------
Type1|1valuea|value1aa
     |1valueb|value1bb
     |1valuec|.....
---------------------------------------------
Type2|2valuea|value2aa
     |2valueb|value2bb
     |2valuec|...
     |2valued|..
---------------------------------------------
Type3|1valuea|...
     |1valueb|...
---------------------------------------------
```

Here in the first column i have 10 rows and for each row in the first column has different number of rows in the second column .

Assume that

```
        First coulmn first  row type 1 has 10 rows in second column

        first column second row type 2 has 5 rows in second column..........
```

Can we create this type of table or should I create New JTable for each rows in first column

Comment: Try taking a look at [*this*](http://www.crionics.com/public/swing_examples/JTableExamples4.html) and [*this*](https://code.google.com/p/spantable/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you need something like a row span.

Please take a look at this topic, it should answer your question:
[Jtable Row Span and Column Span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199392/jtable-row-span-and-column-span)

Hope this will help!